# Can't type the letter 's' in terminal

Tags: command-line, inputrc

I recently tried to disable case sensitivity in the Ubuntu terminal, and ran a few commands to do so. After I got it working properly, it somehow messed with my ability to type, or even copy, a lowercase *s* into terminal.

I have tried changing the inputrc file, but it tells me I do not have permission to do so, and I can't type or copy in 'sudo' into terminal, as it only becomes 'udo'.

How can I regain the ability to type *s* into my terminal? I'm fine with resetting all keybindings and whatnot, I just don't know how to at this point.

Don't know how relevant it is, but the last 3 lines of my *inputrc* file now looks like this:

```
$endif
set completion-ignore-case on
set completion-ignore-case on
```

The commands I ran before the issue occurred were the following (as I had no clue what I was doing):

```
if [ ! -a ~/.inputrc ]; then echo 'source /etc/inputrc' > ~/.inputrc; fi 
echo set completion-ignore-case on | sudo tee -a /etc/inputrc sudo 
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> /etc/inputrc 
echo "bind 'et completion-ignore-cae on'" >> ~/.bahrc
```

Comment: `history` will show your last few  commands, copy and paste it from this page if you can't type it. You could also use an onscreen keyboard, `sudo apt install onboard` (or `florence` is the Gnome onscreen kbd I think). Clearly `echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> /etc/inputrc` messed it up, so `nano /etc/inputrc` and navigate to that line with arrow keys, then ctrl+k to remove the line, ctrl+x, they y, to exit. Might need to restart bash, probably easiest to reboot.

Comment: Similar issue but with letter P; also relates to .inputrc.

Comment: You could try copying `/usr/share/readline/inputrc` (which should be identical to the default `/etc/inputrc`) to your home directory - since you can't type `s` you'd need to do something like `cp $'/u\x73r/\x73hare/readline/inputrc' ~/.inputrc` (or just use the GUI file manager)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the input, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

alt-ctrl-F1 should give you the opportunity to login in a non-X terminal. You should be able to correct things there.